# How to Invalidate cache data manually in ASP.Net WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Suppose I cache data as per below for 10 minutes:

```
cache.Insert(
        key, 
        dt, 
        null, 
        new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.High, 
        null);
```

How do I invalidate the cache before 10 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void ClearApplicationCache()
        {
            List<string> keys = new List<string>();

            IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
            {
                Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option available to you - remove it:

```
cache.Remove(key);
```

Comment: @Thomas Ahh yes I didn't see that in the title, though you should make it clearer in the body. However there's no way to do it manually I'm afraid, not without again writing some kind of page that lets you.